# boto3/aws: resource vs session

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I can use `resource` like this way

```
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket)
```

Also I can use `session` like this way.

```
        session = boto3.session.Session()
        s3_session = session.resource("s3", endpoint_url=self.endpoint_url)
        s3_obj = s3_session.Object(self.bucket, key)
```

Internally, does `session.resource("s3"` uses boto3.resource('s3')?

Comment: No, not necessarily. They might share most of the logic for sure.

Comment: No, it's the other way around, if anything. Using `boto3.client()` is basically the same as `boto3._get_default_session().client()` and similarly for resource.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, people ask about boto3 `client` vs `resource`.

Calls using `client` are direct API calls to AWS, while `resource` is a higher-level Pythonic way of accessing the same information.

In your examples, you are using `session`, which is merely a way of caching credentials. The `session` can then be used for either `client` or `resource`.

For example, when calling the AWS STS [`assume_role()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.assume_role) command, a set of temporary credentials is returned. These can be stored in a `session` and API calls can be made using these credentials.

There is effectively no difference between your code samples, since no specific information has been stored in the `session` object. If you have nothing to specifically configure in the `session`, then you can skip it entirely.